# How can I sunstract ONE value (z) from two vector3's between them?

Tags: vector, lua, roblox

Being more clear, I want to make it so the Z value of a certain vector3 subtracts with the Z value of another vector3, ONLY the Z one, this way making the X and Y values of the first vector3 stay intact, while the only modified one being the Z

These are the specific lines. If these lines do not represent an actual vector3 value, or I've made a mistake which I didn't notice, tell me.

```
local direction = (endPosition - startPosition).Unit * range --I want to subtract the Z value of this vector3...

    if raycast then
       local sth = raycast.Instance.Position --...with the Z value of this other one...
       local mod = vector3(Xdirval, Ydirval, Zmodval) --...and create this supossed new vector3, with the X and Y values of the "direction"'s vector3.
    end
```

I've learned how to get the specific value of vector3's (Z in this case), but I have no idea how to perform arihmetric between the two AND place it in a new vector3, and neither how to extract the vector3 of the items I need (sth's and direction's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply evoke the vector position you want to use.

if you have two vectors:

```
coord1 = vector3(11, 2, 0)
coord2 = vector3(1, 1, 1)
```

you can do mathematical operations as follow

```
print(coord1.x - coord2.x)
>>10
```

Answer (score 0):

Vector arithmetic is pretty simple once you know the trick. You just apply each operation to each component of the vectors.

For example:

```
local a = Vector3.new(1, 2, 3)
local b = Vector3.new(4, 5, 6)

print(a + b) -- returns (5, 7, 9)
print(a - b) -- returns (-3, -3, -3)
print(a * b) -- returns (4, 10, 18)
print(a / b) -- returns (0.25, 0.4, 0.5)
```

So if you wanted to perform an operation on just one component of the vector, you can apply a [mask](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) to the vector that will strip out the other values. More simply put, you multiply the values that you don't care about by zero, and you preserve the ones you do by multiplying them by one.

```
local direction = (endPosition - startPosition).Unit * range

if raycast then
   local pos = raycast.Instance.Position
   local mask = Vector3.new(0, 0, 1)

   -- subtract the position's z value from the direction
   direction -= (pos * mask)
end
```